# Iterate every 5 rows and create a file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel file which I need to convert using python pandas.
I want to create a file for each 5 rows i.e. if I have 29 rows in an excel. I want to create total 6 files. First 5 files consisting of 5 rows each and last file containing of 4 rows. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You shoulod really take the [tour] of the site and go over the [help]. Focus on reading about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. If you keep it like that, your questions will get closed pretty fast as it is not on-topic (at-all) on this site. A general rule of thumb to remember is that this site is not a code giveaway. You are expected to show some efforts on solving your own problem, and ask about a specific part in the code that you had difficulties with. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the whole excel file like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Then, you can split this `df` in batches of 5 rows like this:

```
n = 5  #chunk row size
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
```

`list_df` will have 6 chunks for your case. 5 of them having 5 rows each and the 6th one having 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. `c` is just a counter, `x` is the number of files you will need, and the output files will be named `file_1.xlsx` and so on:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df = pd.read_excel('path_to_your_file.xlsx') # create original df

c = 1
x = math.ceil(df.shape[0]/5)

for i in np.array_split(df, x):
    filename = 'file_'+str(c)
    pd.DataFrame(i).to_excel(filename+'.xlsx', index=False)
    c += 1
```